# Unable to override generic method in java

Tags: java, generics, overriding

```
abstract class Message <T> {
    abstract <T> void setContent(T content) ;
}
class TextMessage extends Message<String> {
     void setContent(String content) {
     }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I am getting errors like

> Main.java:12: error: TextMessage is not abstract and does not override
> abstract method setContent(T) in Message class TextMessage extends
> Message {
> ^   where T is a type-variable:
> T extends Object declared in method setContent(T) 1 error

Comment: The `T` in `Message.setContent` is not the same as the `T` in `Message<T>`. That's because you have added `<T>` to the method. The two `T` generic types have the same name but are definitely not the same. Remove that `<T>` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method declaration:

```
abstract <T> void setContent(T content) ;
```

hides the type parameter declared in class. That causes the error, most probably you don't need that additional type parameter on the method.

Answer (score 0):

The *method* is abstract.  Did you mean to use the class parameter instead?

```
abstract class Message <T> {
    abstract void setContent(T content) ;
}

class TextMessage extends Message<String> {
     void setContent(String content) {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct implementation is:

```
abstract class Message <T> {
    abstract void setContent(T content) ;
}

class TextMessage extends Message<String> {
    @Override
    void setContent(String content) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}

class IntegerMessage extends Message<Integer> {
    @Override
    void setContent(Integer content) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

As you see type parameter has been specified in `TextMessage` and `IntegerMessage` classes

Answer (score -3):

**Not useful**

This may help you, you can code on Intellij Idea which could fix your code.

```
abstract class Message <T> {
    abstract <T> void setContent(T content) ;
}
class TextMessage extends Message<String> {

    <String> void setContent(String content) {
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely misleading, as this creates a typevar named `String` that makes it look like `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Your answer does not explain what causes the problem, neither does it explain the fix. Which causes even more problems by hiding the normally visible type String. I highly doubt that's the desired behaviour. Also IDEs should help the developer with coding, they don't make up for missing knowledge.

Comment: Well, I have awared the short of my answer, thanks for reminding.